# Updating ng-repeat angularJS with mysqli connection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am quite new with AngularJS so excuse me if I'm asking a stupid thing. I'm trying to create a task manager for events with AngularJS + Mysql + PHP.

The layout is separated in two columns. In the left column there's an overview of staff, loaded by function `getUsers()` in `app.js`. By clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button after each `staffname` the `user_id` is being posted in a mysql database table. The results of this table is shown in the right column, function `getEventUsers()` in `app.js`. I'm trying to find out how to reload or update the right table after clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button. The functions itself are working correctly (they get json_encoded results from the `.php` pages), but the right column is not updating itself only after pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> after each click it is showing the correct result. So the right column, so function `getEventUsers()` in `app.js`, has to refresh/reload after clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> button.

### Template

#### `ng-app="myApp"` is in the html tag

#### `ng-controller="usersController"` is in the body tag

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <blockquote><h1>Task Manager</h1></blockquote>
        <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="widget-box" id="recent-box" ng-controller="usersController">
                <div class="widget-header header-color-blue">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4 class="bigger lighter">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>USERS
                </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="filterTask" class="form-control search header-elements-margin" placeholder="Filter Tasks">
                </div>
                </div></div>
                <div class="widget-body ">
                <div class="task">
                    <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="user in users | filter : filterTask">
                    <input 
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="{{user.active}}"
                    ng-checked="user.active==1"
                    ng-click="toggleStatus(user.id,user.active)"/> 
                    <span ng-class="{strike:user.active==0}">{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}} [{{user.id}}]</span>
                    <a ng-click="addEventUser(user.id)" class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                    </label>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">


            <div class="widget-box" id="recent-box" ng-controller="usersController">
            <div class="widget-header header-color-blue">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4 class="bigger lighter">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>EVENT MANAGER
            </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" ng-model="filterTask" class="form-control search header-elements-margin" placeholder="Filter Tasks">
            </div>
            </div></div>
            <div class="widget-body ">
            <div class="task">
                <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="eventuser in eventusers | filter : filterTask">
                <span ng-class="{strike:task.STATUS==2}">{{eventuser.firstname}} [{{eventuser.lastname}}]</span>
                <a ng-click="deleteTask(eventuser.id)" class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
```

#### App.js

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('usersController', function($scope, $http) {

getUsers(); // Load all available users 
function getUsers(){  
$http.post("ajax/getUsers.php").success(function(data){
    $scope.users = data;
    //alert(data);
});
};

getEventUsers(); // Load all available users for event 
function getEventUsers(){  
$http.post("ajax/getEventUsers.php").success(function(data){
    $scope.eventusers = data;       
    //alert(data);
});
};

$scope.addEventUser =  function (user_id) {
$http.post("ajax/addEventUser.php?userid="+user_id).success(function(data){  
    alert(getEventUsers());         
});
};

$scope.toggleStatus = function(item, status) {

if(status=='1'){
    active='0';
}else{
    active='1';
}

$http.post("ajax/updateUsers.php?id="+item+"&active="+active).success(function(data){
   getUsers();
});
};

});
```

Comment: Can you add the html template too?

Comment: Hi Jens, I added the html template a few seconds ago.